# Matlab find percentile curve of a set of scatter points

Tags: matlab, statistics, rank, percentile, non-linear-regression

I have a set of scatter points. They are height of sixty plants (cm) over time(days). I measure each of them for three times (days:~10, ~50, ~100)But some of the plants does not have the second or/and third measurement yet. Here are the small example of my data showing four plants (A,B,C,D).

```
Plant Days  Height     
A     10    2
B     11    5
C     12    4
D     12    5
A     57    7
B     56    8
C     53    6
A     100   12
B     100   10
```

Then I could use `plotmatrix(Days, Height)` to plot the scatter points. I need to make percentile curves (similar to children growth rate) in MATLAB. I tried to use `prctile(height, [25 50 75], 1)` could only output the 25th, 50th and 75th value of height but not a growth rate curve. Could anyone suggest a way to generate the percentile curve of a set of scatter points over time please? Is regression needed to generate a growth rate curve (25th, 50th, 75th) of sixty plants?

Sorry I am still new to Matlab and statistics, please help. Thanks!